# Going from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, GNOME not working properly

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, gnome, upgrade, desktop-environments

I do not get the Activities icon on bottom left instead Trash icon is fixed and the Settings are not able to change my dock but System Settings do change it. What is happening here?

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB and then upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.
These settings do nothing:
[image]
but these do work:
[image]

Also notice the Trash icon on bottom left, I was trying to follow articles on GNOME in Ubuntu 18.04 which have Activities icon instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshots, it's clear that you've logged into a **Unity session** somehow, *not* a GNOME session.

To log into a GNOME session when you boot your system and get to the GDM login screen, you should find a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the '*sign in*' button. If you click the cogwheel you should see an *Ubuntu* option. Select it and log in.

Comment: Woah everything changed it works! is this now default from next time i login ?

Comment: @LordCommander It *should* be remembered for the future logins.